# How can I add images into my .resx file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, image, resources

By other than using AddResource button of Visual Studio, of course.

I submit a form, and an image file with it. In my controller action, I get the `HttpPostedFileBase` object, and its file name by using `Path.GetFileName()`. If I just use `SaveAs()` function to save the image file in my application, I cannot access it later for testing, because it gives me the "Not allowed to load local resource" error.

So I want to add the image to a .resx file and retrieve it later using `ResourceManager` or something. My question is, how can I add the image I have in the controller action into my .resx file?

I should also ask if this is the good approach for the purpose of adding and retrieving image files in my application.

EDITED:
Ok, using .resx to store images is not a good idea. My original problem was that I could save the image file, but when I tried to show it in my view, it gives "Not allowed to load local resource" error.

Here's the controller code:

```
public ActionResult UrunEkle(Urun urun, HttpPostedFileBase image)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Images"));
    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Images"), fileName);
    image.SaveAs(path);  

    urun.ArtUrl = path;

    // other stuff....
}
```

And in my view, I try to retrieve the image like this:

```
<img alt="@urun.name" src="@Url.Content(urun.ArtUrl)" />
```

But using Google Chrome, I get this **"Not allowed to load local resource"**. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Why do you want to use a resource file for this? Resource files are meant for resources that are required to run your application, not store external data.

Comment: Yes, I am getting to that sense also, but I get the  **"Not allowed to load local resource"** error, how can I avoid that for resting purposes?

Comment: Who is giving that error and at what line? Please show some code. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget trying to add the image to a RESX file; it's not designed to be modified at runtime.

Please post some code. The most likely thing is that the URL that you're serving up to use the image later is incorrect. Probably because you're returning the path of the file on the server, not a URL to the image within the context of the web site.

The error message from Chrome is telling you that it's trying to load a resource from the local file system on the client.

Url.Content converts a **relative virtual** path into an **absolute virtual** path and needs a URL starting with ~. You're currently passing in the **absolute physical** path to the image file and Url.Content is returning it, unchanged. You need the relative virtual path (~/App_Data/Images/Untitled.png) in urun.ArtUrl. This is the value that you passed in to Server.MapPath.

Comment: If you View Source in the browser, what's the src attribute got in it?

Comment: `<img alt="NEW ITEM" src="C:\Users\hALO\Desktop\RenkliTablo\RenkliTablo\App_Data\Images\Untitled.png">`

Comment: Now `@Url.Content()` takes **"~/App_Data/Images/Untitled.png"**, and I see `<img alt="son lo" src="/App_Data/Images/Untitled.png">` in the source. But it now gives **"Failed to load resource:..403(Forbidden)"** error for http://localhost:6679/App_Data/Images/Untitled.png, as I see it from Chrome's console

Comment: OK, so we've dealt with your initial problem. Now you have a permissions problem. Look at the permissions on your newly-created Images folder. Try granting read access to Everyone on the Images folder and try again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13576/discussion-between-halo-and-steve-morgan)